# How do I detect if a scriptmanager is on the page?

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

How do I detect if a scriptmanager is loaded on a page?  Some aspx pages have it and others don't and I need a user control to understand this so that it can either load it if needed and also for dealing with viewstate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call [`ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.getcurrent.aspx), which will return `null` if there's no [`ScriptManger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) on the page.